# How to store objects for later use and make them searchable

Tags: c++, class, object, pointers, struct

At the moment I am using a vector to store pointers to the object every time one is made, but that feels a little silly. There's probably a better way, but I haven't found it.

```
What I'm doing:                      Example usage:
```

[image] [image: prototype]

*The problem*:

1. If I want to retrieve a certain Date I have to go over *all* items in the vector to see if RecPaymentsStack.stackDate matches the date the user requested.
2. The RecPaymentStack is actually completely useless at the moment because what I *should* be doing, is, when adding a new item, checking if a "RecPaymentStack.stackDate" has already been made for the new item's Date property, and if so add the new pointer to "RecPayments" to an **array** of pointers inside the "RecPaymentStack" object. But how?

I'm probably unnecessarily complicating things (something I do a lot) so an explenation on how something like this *should* be done would be very nice.

**Detailed info:** (in case I was being too vague)

The below example is supposed to resemble a calendar that can hold certain items (RecPayments) and those items are grouped by their date (RecPaymentsStack).

```
struct RecPayments
{
    std::string name;
    Date* date;
    float cost;
};

struct RecPaymentsStack
{
    Date* stackDate; //This stack's date
    RecPayments * thePaymentItem; //Hold pointer to the actual item
};
```

And here's how I'm currently storing them

```
std::vector<RecPaymentsStack*> RecPaymentsVector; //This vector will hold pointers to all the Recurring Payments

void addRecurring(std::string theDate,std::string theName,float theCost)
{
    //New recurring payment
    RecPayments * newPaymentItem = new RecPayments;
    //Set recurring payment properties
    newPaymentItem->name = theName;
    newPaymentItem->date = new Date(stringToChar(theDate));
    newPaymentItem->cost = theCost;

    //Add recurring payment to stack
    RecPaymentsStack * addToStack = new RecPaymentsStack;
    addToStack->stackDate = new Date(stringToChar(theDate));
    addToStack->thePaymentItem = newPaymentItem;

    //Add pointer to RecPaymentsStack to vector
    RecPaymentsVector.push_back(addToStack);
}
```

So to retrieve the items for a given date, I am currently going over **all** pointers in the vector to see if the "stackDate" property matches the requested date, and if so I use the "thePaymentItem" property to show the actual item.

```
void getItemsNow(Date requestedDate)
{
    std::cout << "Showing Dates for " << requestedDate << std::endl;
    unsigned int i;
    for(i=0;i<RecPaymentsVector.size();i++) //Go over all items in vector
    {
        Date dateInVector(*RecPaymentsVector[i]->stackDate); //Get the date from the vector
        if(dateInVector == requestedDate) //See if Date matches what the user requested
        {
            //Date matched, show user the item properties.
            std::cout << "Date: " << dateInVector <<
                " has name: " << RecPaymentsVector[i]->thePaymentItem->name <<
                " and price " << RecPaymentsVector[i]->thePaymentItem->cost <<
                std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

3 problems with this:

1. Going over all items in the vector is highly inefficient if I only
   need a couple of pointers
2. The RecPaymentStack is actually completely useless at the moment because what I *should* be doing, is, when adding a new item, checking if a "RecPaymentStack.stackDate" has already been made for the new item's Date property, and if so add the new pointer to "RecPayments" to an **array** of pointers inside the "RecPaymentStack" object. But how?
3. All of this feels extremely silly to begin with.. there's probably a much easier/professional way to do this but I can't find out what, probably because I'm still thinking like a PHPer.

So the general idea here is that I end up doing something like (silly example)

```
for each RecPaymentsStack->stackDate //For each unique Date, show it's children items.
{
    cout << "The Date is " CurrentRecPaymentsStack->stackDate and it holds the following items:
    for each CurrentRecPaymentsStack->thePaymentItem //This would now be an array of pointers
    {
        cout << "item name " CurrentRecPaymentsStack->thePaymentItem->name << " with cost " << CurrentRecPaymentsStack->thePaymentItem->cost << endl;
    }
}
```

Which would basically go over all the unique "RecPaymentsStack" objects (unique determined by it's "Date" property) and for each Date it would then show it's "children" from the RecPayments struct.

And there has to be some way to search for a particular date without having to go over **all** the available ones.

Comment: *This* is how some question on SO should've been written - details to the last point. Btw, on your last point: binary trees and search.

Comment: It is good to have visualization. But it would be even better has it been more compact.

Comment: You get a +1 just for the effort and sincerity of the question.

Comment: Am I correct to assume that you don't know what a `reference` in C++ is?

Comment: First of all, get rid of all the pointers and `new`s. You don't need them, vector stores the contained elements in free store memory anyway and does the memory managment for you.

Comment: Possibly `std::map<RecPaymentsStack>` would be a useful data structure.

Comment: sounds like a question for codereview.se. +1 for the nice visual btw :)

Comment: Do you plan to accumulate the old records for ever, or do you plan to utilize some sort of a cache cleaning (LRU?) mechanism?

Comment: @OrenS. In a real application, this would probably have a GUI. I think I'd write all dates belong to a year the user isn't currently viewing to the HDD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using a vector to manage your items, you should replace your `RecPaymentsStack` instance with a [`std::multimap`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/multimap/). The key type is your `Date` structure, the value type is `RecPayments` (which I would change to the singular form `RecPayment`). Small example (untested):

```
typedef std::multimap<Date, RecPayment> RecPaymentsByDateMap;
typedef std::pair<RecPaymentsByDateMap::iterator, 
                  RecPaymentsByDateMap::iterator>
                                        RecPaymentsByDateMapIters;

RecPaymentsByDateMap payments_by_date;

RecPaymentsByDateMapIters findByDate(Date date) {
  return payments_by_date.equal_range(date);
}

...

// find all payments with the given date
RecPaymentsByDateMapIters iters = findByDate(...);
for (RecPaymentsByDateMap::iterator it = iters.first;
     it != iters.second;
     ++it)
{
  std::cout << "Payment " << it->second.name << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error at `return payments_by_date.equal_range(date);` which sais `error: no match for ‘operator<’ in ‘__x < __y’`. It also sais `note: candidates are: operator<(Drep, Drep) <built-in>`. Kerrek's answer nets a similar error. It probably has something to do with the way the [Date class](http://www.glenmccl.com/misc_013.htm) works but I can't figure it out, even after an hour of trial and error.

Comment: you need to implement the `operator<` method for your Date class so multimap can store your keys efficiently

Comment: I added `Date operator < (Date);` to the `public` section of the `Date` class. Resulting in `error: passing ‘const Date’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘Date Date::operator<(Date)’ discards qualifiers`. I read somewhere that "Calling a non-const function from a const function will generate this error." but `Date operator < (Date) const;` results in `undefined reference to Date::operator<(Date) const'`. As you probably noticed, I have no idea what I'm doing anymore. I have yet to find a tutorial on this that handles my exact same situation, are you aware of one?

Comment: hm, the `operator<` should return a boolean value, so try the signatur `boolean Date::operator<(const Date& other) const;` (the ampersand says that the argument is a reference to, rather than a copy of the given value (this is a special C++ thing not available in C)

Comment: When I put that inside the Date class (public section) I get `error: extra qualification ‘Date::’ on member ‘operator<’`. Placing it outside of the class rresults in `error: no ‘bool Date::operator<(const Date&) const’ member function declared in class ‘Date’` and removing the `Date::` from that gives `error: non-member function ‘bool operator<(const Date&)’ cannot have cv-qualifier` ;X

Comment: You seem to have problems with adding a member function to your class. As this problem is not related to the original question, please consider accepting one of the answers here and opening a new question for your new problem :)

Comment: I find it a little weird to accept an answer even though I'm not 100% sure it solves my problem (can't test it with this error) but you're probably right.

Comment: In that case you can not accept it yet and still open a new question in the meantime.

Comment: Because you already accepted this: here is my solution to your `operator<` problem: http://pastebin.com/dqfVcMbT

Comment: Thanks so much, it's working now. I can't believe I put the operator in the class but completely forgot to create the actual function for it in the main script... that's just stupid :X

Answer (score 1):

I might design it like this -- this is just a loose idea, details should be adjusted according to your requirements:

```
#include <deque>
#include <map>
#include <string>

struct RecPayment
{
    std::string name;
    Date        date;
    float       cost;
};

struct RecPaymentsStack
{
    Date stackDate;
    std::deque<RecPayment> thePaymentItem;

    bool operator<(RecPaymentsStack const & rhs) const
    {
      return stackDate < rhs.stackDate;
    }

    explicit RecPaymentsStack(Date const & d) : stackDate(d) { }
};

typedef std::multimap<RecPaymentsStack> PaymentsCollection;
```

Now you can insert elements:

```
PaymentsCollection payments;

{
  auto it = payments.emplace(Date("..."));
  it->thePaymentItem.emplace_back(Payment{name1, date1, cost1});
  it->thePaymentItem.emplace_back(Payment{name2, date2, cost2});
  it->thePaymentItem.emplace_back(Payment{name3, date3, cost3});
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error at `return stackDate < rhs.stackDate;` which sais `no match for ‘operator<’ in ‘((const RecPaymentsStack*)this)->RecPaymentsStack::stackDate < rhs->RecPaymentsStack::stackDate’`. It also sais `note: candidates are: operator<(Drep, Drep) <built-in>`. Niklas' answer nets a similar error. It probably has something to do with the way the [Date class](http://www.glenmccl.com/misc_013.htm) works but I can't figure it out, even after an hour of trial and error.

Comment: @natli: Same answer: Design your `Date` class so it has a comparison operator.